# How to detect mouseover on touch mobile devices in the below code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a magnify glass on my page. when you perform mouseover over an image it will show you the magnifying glass with zoomed image part in it and you can also move that magnifying glass over an image. The only problem is this code doesn't work with mobile devices as they don't use mouseover.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var native_width = 0;
 var native_height = 0;
  $(".large").css("background","url('" + $(".thumb").attr("src") + "') no-repeat");

 $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e){
  //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
  //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
  //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
  if(!native_width && !native_height)
  {
   //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
   //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
   //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
   //created this image object.
   var image_object = new Image();
   image_object.src = $(".thumb").attr("src");
   
   //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
   //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
   //the image gets loaded.
   native_width = image_object.width;
   native_height = image_object.height;
  }
  else
  {
   //x/y coordinates of the mouse
   //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
   var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
   //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
   //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
   //container(.magnify)
   var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
   var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;
   
   //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
   if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0)
   {
    $(".large").fadeIn(100);
   }
   else
   {
    $(".large").fadeOut(100);
   }
   if($(".large").is(":visible"))
   {
    //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
    //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
    //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
    //large image inside the magnifying glass
    var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".thumb").width()*native_width - $(".large").width()/2)*-1;
    var ry = Math.round(my/$(".thumb").height()*native_height - $(".large").height()/2)*-1;
    var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";
    
    //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
    var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
    var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;
    
    //Now the glass moves with the mouse
    //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
    //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates
    
    //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
    $(".large").css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
   }
  }
 })
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html { height: 101%; }
body { 
  background: #e4e4e4 url('images/binding_light.png'); /* http://subtlepatterns.com/binding-light/ */
  font-size: 62.5%; 
  line-height: 1; 
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

::selection { background: #d0ccf1; }
::-moz-selection { background: #d0ccf1; }
::-webkit-selection { background: #d0ccf1; }

br { display: block; line-height: 2.2em; } 

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

input, textarea { 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none; 
}

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; } 

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

h1 { 
 position: relative;
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.65em;
  line-height: 2.0em;
  padding: .2em 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #5d6c81;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-align: center;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
 content: "";
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
 height: 2px;
 
 vertical-align: middle;
 background: #5d6c81;
}
h1:before {    
 left: -.5em;
 margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
}
h1:after {    
 left: .5em;
 margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
}
h1 > span {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 white-space: normal;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Geneva, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #777;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

p,span { font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #424242; }

p { font-size: 1.7em; line-height: 1.4em; }

a { text-decoration: none; color: #577ccf; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }


/** layout contents **/
#w {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 13px 22px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}



/** images **/
.imgbox {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.imgbox img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 4px 9px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 4px 9px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 9px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.credits { text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px; }

.magnify {width: 600px; margin: 50px auto; position: relative; cursor: none;}

/* Let's create the magnifying glass */
.large {
 display: none;
 width: 175px; 
 height: 175px;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
 -moz-border-radius: 100%;
 border-radius: 100%;
 
 /* box shadows to achieve the glass effect */
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}

/* To solve overlap bug at the edges during magnification */
.thumb { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Image Zoom Viewer Demo</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://spyrestudios.com/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://spyrestudios.com/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
 
  
</head>


<body>
  <div id="w">
    <h1>Image Magnify Effect</h1>
    <p>Just hover over the image below to see a full-scaled zoomed effect.</p>

    <div class="magnify">
     <div class="large"></div><!-- This is the magnifying glass which will contain the original/large version -->
 
     <!-- Image source http://www.flickr.com/photos/rustyangel/4509569191/ -->
     <div class="imgbox"><img src="https://s18.postimg.org/arieodetl/01-psx-controller.jpg" width="600" height="398" class="thumb" /></div>
 
    </div><!-- @end .magnify -->
    
    
  </div><!-- @end #w -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mouseover kind of works in mobile devices. If someone taps it, mouseover works but then if someone taps anywhere else, the mouseover stops.

Comment: Mouse over on mobile happens when theres a slight pressure on the screen.

Comment: Anyway, there is the equivalent of mobile mousemove for JavaScript and it's called **touchmove**. You can check it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove

Answer (score 1):

for **JS** you can go for:
`$("yourElementGoesHere").addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);`

for **CSS** you can go for: `element:hover, element:active { your properties here; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none}`